# Does a rel=canonical link remove all SEO value from the page?

Tags: seo, canonical-link

Here'y the story: I have a website for a local company that publishes quality content to an on-site blog. We're expanding to a new geographic region, and I'm in the process of building another website targeting the new region.

I'd like to include a blog on the new website, which will pull in any content/posts from our existing blog. I primarily want to do this for the added SEO benefit of having fresh, relevant content that's frequently updated on your website. However, I would of course need to add a rel=canonical link back to the original blog in order to ensure I don't get any duplicate content penalties from posting the same content across two separate domains.

My question is whether adding that rel=canonical link will eliminate the SEO value of that content being posted to the new website?

I'm not really talking about which blog post would show up in SERPs, as I understand that the point of the rel=canonical tag is to provide attribution to the primary source of the content. I'm more concerned about whether using a rel=canonical on the content would eliminate the secondary SEO benefit of having relevant, frequently updated content on your website, due to Google being essentially "blind" to the duplicate content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases the answer on your question is "yes". With regard to Google - [GoogleAnswers](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394) (see the last question). 
Other search engines can not maintain this attribute.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you pull content from somewhere else to post, it isn't "fresh".   Fresh content is newly written.   You won't get any credit for fresh content whether or not you use rel=canonical

Answer (score 0):

The canonical tag behaves in a similar way to a 301 redirect. That is, ranking that the page with the canonical tag has will mostly get transferred to the page it points it.